# JavaScript how to modify numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm want to generate an array with **5 random numbers** from *1 to 100*, then check if the number is even, if not I want to modify it by adding 1.

EXAMPLE:

`array = [7, 13, 2, 60, 93]`

And the outcome should be

`modified_array = [8, 14, 2, 60, 94]` but I'm stuck..

I'd appreciate it if somebody will help me with fixing it. Thanks!

```js
const array = []
const modified_array = []
while (array.length < 5) {
  i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  array.push(i);
  for (i in array);
  if (i % 2 !== 0) {
    modified_array.push(i)
  }
}

console.log("array");
console.log(array);
console.log("-------------------------")
console.log("modified_array");
console.log(modified_array);
```

Comment: why not have two functions? one to generate the original array, and the second to modify the array?

Comment: Also, doesn't it make more sense to generate 5 random *odd* numbers from the start?

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the half max value and multiply with 2?

```js
const array = [];
while (array.length < 5) {
    array.push(2 * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1));
}

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 to the current value if it is not an even number else add the value as it is to the modified array.

```js
const array = []
const modified_array = []
while (array.length < 5) {
    i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    array.push(i);
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        modified_array.push(i + 1);
    }else{
        modified_array.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(...array);
console.log(...modified_array);
```

Comment: `modified_array.push(i + (i%2));`

Answer (score 0):

You just need one variable and one for loop to work with this solution. When you are appending the element to the array just check it then if it is even. If it is not then just increment its value

```
for(i = 0; i<5; i++) {
  array.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1))
  if(array[i] % 2 != 0) {
    array[i] += 1
  }
}

console.log(array)
```